# Getting $\frac{2\pi}{\hbar}$ factor in Fermi's Golden Rule without using limit of no time dependence

Tags: quantum-mechanics, probability, perturbation-theory, fermis-golden-rule

[Fermi's golden rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%27s_golden_rule) is: $$R = \frac{2\pi}{\hbar} |\langle f| \Delta H_0 |i \rangle|^2 \rho(E)$$ and it looks like all derivations of this at some point use the limit of a time dependent perturbation becoming essentially time constant. My question is, if we assume a time constant perturbation from the start, how can we get this $\frac{2\pi}{\hbar}$ factor since it should be consistent?

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/606509/2451

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where does the $\frac{2\pi}{\hbar}$ come from in Fermi's Golden Rule?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/606509/)

Comment: Maybe section 3.6.1 [here](https://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft/qft.pdf#page=77) is what you're looking for? The time-dependent in (3.77) is not due to the potential it's due to to the eigenbasis, if you can re-derive this and the next few steps with $\hbar$ re-inserted you will see where it comes from.

Comment: Ahh I see thanks @bolbteppa. If you don't, I may write that up as an answer to this thanks.